# Passing information dosn't work with intents

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, bundle

I set information into an intent, with putExtra(), and i check with my debugger that the info is really there (and it is), then i start another activity:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

but when i try to access the stored information:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
```

then it returns null, actually, i see with my debugger that the intent has no bundle attached to it.

How can this be resolved?

---

**EDIT:  here is how i put the extras:**

This is the function i use:

```
private Intent baseClickFunction(JSONItem item){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("title", item.getProductName());
    i.putExtra("date", item.getTimestamp());
    i.putExtra("content", item.getFullDescription());

    return i;
}

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(baseClickFunction((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)));    

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

As i said before, i checked with my debugger that the info is really in my intent before starting a new activity (and it is).

i even tried to do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("title", ((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)).getProductName());
                i.putExtra("date", ((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)).getTimestamp());
                i.putExtra("content", ((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)).getFullDescription());
                startActivity(i);
```

and it dosnt work

EDIT: Does the fact that i set the listener on which i am doing this in the "protected void onPostExecute(Void result)" of an AsyncTask have any effect on any of this?

EDIT: When i do this in another project it works, but in this one it wont...
Do AsyncTasks, ListViews or tabViews have any effect on this?

Comment: Please post the code that sets the extras.

Comment: where you are setting the data ? or please provide the code that you using to set the data to intent, what data you want to pass ?

Comment: i try this in another project it works, but it refuses to work here!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
        {
            startActivity(baseClickFunction((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)));
        }
    });
```

You probably override the bundle with the following line...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(baseClickFunction((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)));
```

And it's really not needed to create a new Intent because your method already returns an Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are putting the extras in the intent before you are calling `startActivity(intent)`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putExtra(...);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Looks like you are already doing this. Posted before additional information was there.

Answer (score 0):

if you do:

```
intent.putExtra("yourkey", value);
```

you can retrive with

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getIntExtra("yourKey", defaultValue);
```

if you want to use bundle you have to add values to the bundle and then put the bundle into the intent, with

```
intent.putExtras(bundle)
```

before the `startActivity()`

Comment: i am doing all of that, and when i check with my debuger, i see that before starting the next activity that in the intent is all of my data, but in the secound activtiy i check again and there is no data

Comment: just to be clear you are putting your values int the intent with intent.putExtra(...)  and try to read this through Bundle b = intent.getExtras(); ?

Comment: that s wrong. to retrive the value use, for instance, getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

Answer (score 0):

It's happening becasue you are creating a new intent wihtout the extras attached.

You are attaching the extras to `intent i` but starting the activity with `intent intent`.  Rather than create a new intent, set the intent you are going to use to the returned intent from your function.  Like this:

`Intent intent = baseClickFunction((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position));`

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried doing this : Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemActivity.class);
           i.putExtra("title", ((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)).getProductName());
           i.putExtra("date", ((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)).getTimestamp());
           i.putExtra("content", ((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)).getFullDescription());
        startActivity(i);  and it still dosnt work

Comment: I meant for you to leave your function alone (since it seems to be working as you can see the data there) and try the single line of code I posted in place of the portion where you have `Intent intent = new Intent(baseClickFunction((JSONItem) a.getItemAtPosition(position)));`